# recvfrom() incorrectly reports sender info in UDP from parallels vm

Tags: python, sockets, udp, multicast, parallels

When I send UDP multicast from Windows vm (Parallels) and read it on my OS X El Capitan host with recvfrom, the "sender" info returned by recvfrom matches the adaptor it was received on on the mac and not the adaptor it was sent from on the windows machine like it was supposed to.

Also, if I run the same code to send UDP packets from OS X they won't be received on the Windows vm. But sending between two Windows VM's works perfectly, and the "sender" info is returned properly.

Maybe I need to bind the OS X sender to a specific interface? It would be good to send over all interfaces if possible. I'm not sure if this is a networking problem, or a parallels problem, or some other problem.

**Windows:**: 10.211.5.8

**OS X:** 192.168.1.65, 10.211.55.2, 10.37.129.2

sender:

```
import socket, struct
addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo('225.0.0.250', None)[0]
s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ttl_bin = struct.pack('@i', MYTTL)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl_bin)
data = repr(time.time()) + '\0'
s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), (addrinfo[4][0], MYPORT))
```

receiver:

```
import socket, struct
addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo('225.0.0.250', None)[0]
s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', MYPORT))
group_bin = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('=I', socket.INADDR_ANY)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, more)
data, sender = s.recvfrom(1500)
print(str(sender) + '  ' + repr(data))
```

Windows vm sender -> OS X receiver ('192.168.1.65' is receiver):

```
('192.168.1.65', 62958)  b'1462856664.784149\x00'
('192.168.1.65', 62958)  b'1462856665.7842436\x00'
('192.168.1.65', 62958)  b'1462856666.7843592\x00'
('192.168.1.65', 62958)  b'1462856667.7846606\x00'
```

Windows vm sender -> Windows vm receiver ('10.211.55.3' is sender):

```
('10.211.55.3', 54936)  b'1462856959.228\x00'
('10.211.55.3', 54936)  b'1462856960.242\x00'
('10.211.55.3', 54936)  b'1462856961.256\x00'
('10.211.55.3', 54936)  b'1462856962.27\x00'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there some port translation done by the vm?

Comment: What would be an example of that? Do you mean like a NAT setup? It's just a plain Windows 10 install with the firewall turned off, using the default shared network which both machines exist on and can ping, access other TCP ports, etc.